# Why is my urls.py file not being detected?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I just created a new app for my django project and have created a urls.py, models.py, views.py, and serializers.py. However, my project is not detecting the URLs in the urls.py file. If I go to a different app in my project and edit the urls.py file, the system detects it. However, it will not detect it in the new one. Here is the urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^knorket-kaitongo-integration/$', views.KnorketKaitongoIntegration.as_view(),
        name='knorket_kaitongo_integration'),
]
```

Does anyone know why this wouldn't be detected? It's not showing up on the API screen either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django does not autodetect any files
You need to install them using the installed_apps list and register URLs.

In the Root application, you should find a urls.py file, in that file you need to register your URLs.

[image]

You need to import application URLs in Root urls.py and add them in something like this.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('^', include(urls))
]
```